# Flutter | How to run code from external file?

Tags: flutter, multiprocessing

I am wondering if it is possible to execute a complete dart file from a running instance, but the code is coming from an external file?
So for example:
I have a home screen app with one button.
If I click the button, it loads an external file which is a complete dart file with the text "Hello", and execute that file basically, so the user moves to the new page.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practically it is not possible in applications.
When you run or create an `.apk` of your code, your project gets all code and created a copy of that code which machine understands.
So for that you will require your whole code at once and you cannot put togather the code into pices.